# How to make custom filter in android using base adapter?

Tags: java, android

Can you please tell me how to make custom filter in android using base adapter ?
I have made a simple demo of auto complete. I take array of string in which there is 2250 entries with **Name and code** like that example **"Alexandra Palace-(AAP)",** first name is given and the it code inside the bracket.my issue is I need to filter this using code not by name .In other word if i type anything in input field it filter with starting characters of element mean  name I need to filter with code which is inside the bracket.

**Code:**

```
package com.firstgroup.global;
public class GlobalList {

    public static String[] stationList={
        "MNCRLWY-(LWY)",
        "Lympstone Commando-(LYC)",
        "Lydney-(LYD)",
        "Lye-(LYE)",
        "Lympstone Village-(LYM)",
        "Lymington Pier-(LYP)",
        "Lymington Town-(LYT)",
        "Lazonby & Kirkoswald-(LZB)",
        "Leeds, Whitehall (Bus)-(LZZ)",
        "Macclesfield-(MAC)",
        "Maghull-(MAG)",
        "Maidenhead-(MAI)",
        "Malden Manor-(MAL)",
        "Manchester Piccadilly-(MAN)",
        "Martins Heron-(MAO)",
        "Margate-(MAR)",
        "Manors-(MAS)",
        "Matlock-(MAT)",
        "Mauldeth Road-(MAU)",
        "Mallow-(MAW)",
        "Maxwell Park-(MAX)",
        "Maybole-(MAY)",
        "Millbrook (Hampshire)-(MBK)",
        "Middlesbrough-(MBR)",
        "Moulsecoomb-(MCB)",
        "Metro Centre-(MCE)",
        "March-(MCH)",
        "Marne La Vallee-(MCK)",
        "Morecambe-(MCM)",
        "Machynlleth-(MCN)",
        "Manchester Oxford Road-(MCO)",
        "Manchester Victoria-(MCV)",
        "Maidstone Barracks-(MDB)",
        "Maidstone East-(MDE)",
        "Midgham-(MDG)",
        "Middlewood-(MDL)",
        "Maiden Newton-(MDN)",
        "Morden South-(MDS)",
        "Maidstone West-(MDW)",
        "MAERDY-(MDY)",
        "Meols Cop-(MEC)",
        "Meldreth-(MEL)",
        "Menheniot-(MEN)",
        "Meols-(MEO)",
        "Meopham-(MEP)",
        "Merthyr Tydfil-(MER)",
        "Melton-(MES)",
        "Merthyr Vale-(MEV)",
        "Maesteg (Ewenny Road)-(MEW)",
        "Mexborough-(MEX)",
        "Merryton-(MEY)",
        "Morfa Mawddach-(MFA)",
        "Minffordd-(MFD)",
        "Minffordd-(MFF)",
        "Milford Haven-(MFH)",
        "Mount Florida-(MFL)",
        "Mansfield-(MFT)",
        "Metheringham-(MGM)",
        "Marston Green-(MGN)",
        "Minehead-(MHD)",
        "Merstham-(MHM)",
        "Market Harborough-(MHR)",
        "Meadowhall-(MHS)",
        "Manchester Airport-(MIA)",
        "Micheldever-(MIC)",
        "Millfield (T & W Metro)-(MIF)",
        "Mills Hill-(MIH)",
        "Mitcham Junction-(MIJ)",
        "Micklefield-(MIK)",
        "Mill Hill Broadway-(MIL)",
        "Moreton-in-Marsh-(MIM)",
        "Milliken Park-(MIN)",
        "Mirfield-(MIR)",
        "Mistley-(MIS)",
        "Milton Keynes Central-(MKC)",
        "Melksham-(MKM)",
        "Market Rasen-(MKR)",
        "Marks Tey-(MKT)",
        "Millbrook (Bedfordshire)-(MLB)",
        "Mouldsworth-(MLD)",
        "Milford (Surrey)-(MLF)",
        "Mallaig-(MLG)",
        "Mill Hill (Lancashire)-(MLH)",
        "Millom-(MLM)",
        "Milngavie-(MLN)",
        "MILESPL-(MLP)",
        "Milnrow-(MLR)",
        "Melrose (Bus)-(MLS)",
        "Malton-(MLT)",
        "Marlow-(MLW)",
        "Morley-(MLY)",
        "Melton Mowbray-(MMO)",
        "Markinch-(MNC)",
        "Manea-(MNE)",
        "Manningtree-(MNG)",
        "Menston-(MNN)",
        "Manor Park-(MNP)",
        "Manor Road-(MNR)",
        "MINZHBF-(MNZ)",
        "Mobberley-(MOB)",
        "Moorgate-(MOG)",
        "Monifieth-(MON)",


    };

}
```

when I type **"lwy"** it will not show **"MNCRLWY-(LWY)",** can you please tell how I will achieve this ?

here is my code..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_station);

    autocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item_autoComplete);

    STATION_LIST = new String[GlobalList.stationList.length
            + GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length];
    System.arraycopy(GlobalList.stationList, 0, STATION_LIST, 0,
            GlobalList.stationList.length);
    System.arraycopy(GlobalExtendStationList.stationList, 0,
            STATION_LIST, GlobalList.stationList.length,
            GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length);
    autosuggestAdapter = new CustomAutocompletAdapter(this,STATION_LIST);
    autocompleteView.setAdapter(autosuggestAdapter);
```

**customAutosuggestAdapter:**

```
public class CustomAutocompletAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    String[] autolistArray;
    private Context context;
    public CustomAutocompletAdapter( Context context, String[] autolistArray){
        this.autolistArray=autolistArray;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_adapter, null);
            }

            final TextView stationNameAndCode = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_selectStationName);



            final String stationNameAndCodeValue = autolistArray[position];


            stationNameAndCode.setText(stationNameAndCodeValue);


            return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {

                System.out.println("Constraint " + constraint);
                Log.d("-----------", "publishResults");
                // has


            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                   Log.d("-----------", "performFiltering");
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); // Holds the
                                                                // results of a
                                                                // filtering
                                                                // operation in
                                                                // values
                 /********
                 * 
                 * If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns
                 * the mOriginalValues(Original) values else does the Filtering
                 * and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
                 * 
                 ********/

                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

                constraint = (String) constraint
                        .toString().toLowerCase(locale);
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // set the Original result to return
                } else {

                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //convert object to string
                Log.d("-----------", "convertResultToString");
                return "";
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

**It is not showing no auto suggest**. Could you please tell how I will achieve this? Mean filter functionality?
I want to add filter method when I type in input field it filter from code not from name..

Comment: You haven't doing any filter operations in your filter class

Comment: that I need to aad ..do you HAVE ANY IDEA.I don't know from where I will start ..

Comment: @Shruthi have checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android if you dont understand then i will give you full code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter?rq=1

Comment: @kalyanpvs I understand but could u please give whole code

Comment: @kalyanpvs can you please tie you id will send my code

Comment: here one of example how to filter data in Adapter with Filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26506506/3864698

Comment: @kalyanpvs please check mail

Comment: @Shruthi ok..i will check

Comment: @Shruti yeah...wait i will post

Comment: @Shruti some of them have two brackets..what about that??

Comment: I didn't get..can you please elaborate which bracket you are saying ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63585/discussion-between-shruti-and-kalyan-pvs).

Comment: @Shruti have you tested?? is it working??

Comment: @kalyanpvs it is working great answer..Net problem that why I did not able to tell.Secondly I have Querry when I write first chaharecter performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) constraint give null value but after that gives correct value .example if I write "p" it give null .Then i if I write "pa" it give constraint give "pa"..why it gives first time null value..

Comment: @Shruti ok..for first time i have changed..have you changed like that..

Comment: @Shruti ok..wait i will check and tell you..

Comment: @Shruti autocompleteView.setThreshold(1); will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Adapter like this

```
public class CustomAutocompletAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private String stationNameAndCodeValue;
ArrayList<String> autolistArray;
ArrayList<String> objects;
private Context context;

public CustomAutocompletAdapter(Context context, String[] autolistArray) {
    this.autolistArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < autolistArray.length; i++) {
        this.autolistArray.add(autolistArray[i]);

    }
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return autolistArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return autolistArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_adapter, null);
    }

    final TextView stationNameAndCode = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.item_selectStationName);

    stationNameAndCodeValue = autolistArray.get(position);

    stationNameAndCode.setText(stationNameAndCodeValue);

    return v;
}

Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {

        System.out.println("Constraint " + constraint);
        Log.d("-----------", "publishResults");
        if (results.count > 0 && results != null) {
            autolistArray = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.d("-----------", "performFiltering");
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        List<String> filteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (objects == null) {
            objects = new ArrayList<String>(autolistArray);
        }
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // set the Original result to return
            results.count = objects.size();
            results.values = objects;

        } else {
            constraint = (String) constraint.toString().toLowerCase(locale);
            Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("-\\((.*?)\\)");
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                String name = objects.get(i);
                // System.out.println(name);

                Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(name);
                String subText = "";
                while (matchPattern.find()) {
                    subText = matchPattern.group(1);
                }
                if (subText.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)) {
                    filteredArrList.add(name);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(filteredArrList);
            // set the Filtered result to return
            results.count = filteredArrList.size();
            results.values = filteredArrList;

        }
        return results;
    }

};

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return myFilter;
}
}
```