# Search in listview via searchview

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview

I have some troubles with my search in listview. I create my custom array adapter with Filter. If the result is correct then it always shows only the first item. When I use base array adapter the result is shown as correct but I need to use the custom adapter. Can you help me? This is my code of the array adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> original;
    ArrayList<String> fitems;
    int layoutId;
    int textId;
    int imageId;
    private Filter filter;
    ImageAdapter(Activity context, int layoutId, int textId, int imageId, ArrayList<String> data){
        super(context,layoutId,data);
        this.context = context;
        this.original = new ArrayList<>(data);
        this.fitems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
        this.textId = textId;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(textId);
        label.setText(original.get(position));
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(imageId);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        return(row);
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new ListFilter();
        return filter;
    }
    private class ListFilter extends Filter{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint){
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0){
                ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(original);
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();
            }
            else{
                ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(original);
                ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                final int count = values.size();
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                    final String value = values.get(i);
                    final String valueText = values.get(i).toLowerCase();
                    if (valueText.startsWith(prefix)){
                        nlist.add(valueText);
                    }
                    else{
                        final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                        final int wordCount = words.length;
                        // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
                        for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                            if (words[k].startsWith(prefix)) {
                                nlist.add(value);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
            }
            return results;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            fitems = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i=0; i<fitems.size(); i++){
                String str = fitems.get(i);
                add(str);
            }
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {                            
                        if(EventForList.size()!=0) {                               
                            imAdapter2.getFilter().filter("");
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"List is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {                            
                        if(EventForList.size()!=0) {                                
                            imAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"List is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: This link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26506506/3864698

Comment: It aren`t work without 
clear();
for (int i=0; i<fitems.size(); i++)
  add(fitems.get(i)); in the publishResults.
But my promblem isn`t solved. It`s showed only the first item